# Decode HTTP/3 Frame payload in wireshark

Tags: http, wireshark, packet-sniffers, quic

I have a quic packet captured and decrypted it using TLS keys. I would like to see different fields of the HTTP request/response. But I only see frame-payload and nothing else.
[image]

I would like to know what are the resourses requested and the responses.

Comment: which version of wireshark are you using?

Comment: @Peter I am using version 4.0.5 on Windows 11 Home

Answer (score 2):

The wireshark dissector for HTTP/3 was not ready yet. Only recently (end of august '23) support for HTTP/3 HEADERS/QPACK was added on 4.1 dev branch.

Answer (score 0):

Now, even Wireshark 4.2.2 is out and installing it together with the   HTTP/3 library with QUIC and QPACK, you can dissect HTTP3 messages.

Install `libnghttp3-0` (on Ubuntu) as well.

[Dissected HTTP3 headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPXkG.png)